# How to use Conscrypt with Apache HttpClient 5 to speed up TLS

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

What is the recommended way to use Conscrypt with Apache HttpClient 5?

I've tried adding the `conscrypt-openjdk-uber-2.2.1.jar` jar to my classpath and configuring my `sslcontext` as `SSLContexts.custom().setProvider(Conscrypt.newProvider())`, but when I test HttpClient with that `sslcontext` it throws:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec - 
Recoverable I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when processing request to 
{s}->https://www.wikipedia.org:443
```

If I remove the custom `setProvider` line then it works perfectly (via regular JSSE).

I notice that Conscrypt is listed as a dependency here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/httpclient5/dependencies.html, so perhaps there is built-in support for Conscrypt that I need to enable somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need to do anything. HttpClient automatically detects and configures `Conscrypt` as a provider for its async TLS layer on Java 1.7 and 1.8.

For all newer JREs one can explicitly configure the connection manager to use `Conscrypt` based TLS strategy:

```
PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setTlsStrategy(ConscryptClientTlsStrategy.getSystemDefault())
        .build();
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.NEGOTIATE)
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();
```

**UPDATED**

The following code snippet works for me with HttpClient 5.0-beta7

```
final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .setProvider(Conscrypt.newProvider())
        .build();
final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
        .setSslContext(sslcontext)
        .build();
final HttpClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
        .build();
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build()) {

    final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.wikipedia.org/");

    System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getMethod() + " " + httpget.getUri());

    final HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, clientContext)) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getCode() + " " + response.getReasonPhrase());

        final SSLSession sslSession = clientContext.getSSLSession();
        if (sslSession != null) {
            System.out.println("SSL protocol " + sslSession.getProtocol());
            System.out.println("SSL cipher suite " + sslSession.getCipherSuite());
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Executing request GET https://www.wikipedia.org/
2020-02-06 10:33:22,619 DEBUG ex-00000001: preparing request execution
2020-02-06 10:33:22,625 DEBUG Cookie spec selected: strict
2020-02-06 10:33:22,629 DEBUG Auth cache not set in the context
2020-02-06 10:33:22,629 DEBUG ex-00000001: target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2020-02-06 10:33:22,630 DEBUG ex-00000001: proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2020-02-06 10:33:22,630 DEBUG ex-00000001: acquiring connection with route {s}->https://www.wikipedia.org:443
2020-02-06 10:33:22,630 DEBUG ex-00000001: acquiring endpoint (3 MINUTES)
2020-02-06 10:33:22,632 DEBUG ex-00000001: endpoint lease request (3 MINUTES) [route: {s}->https://www.wikipedia.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 25]
2020-02-06 10:33:22,636 DEBUG ex-00000001: endpoint leased [route: {s}->https://www.wikipedia.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 25]
2020-02-06 10:33:22,649 DEBUG ex-00000001: acquired ep-00000000
2020-02-06 10:33:22,649 DEBUG ex-00000001: acquired endpoint ep-00000000
2020-02-06 10:33:22,649 DEBUG ex-00000001: opening connection {s}->https://www.wikipedia.org:443
2020-02-06 10:33:22,650 DEBUG ep-00000000: connecting endpoint (3 MINUTES)
2020-02-06 10:33:22,650 DEBUG ep-00000000: connecting endpoint to https://www.wikipedia.org:443 (3 MINUTES)
2020-02-06 10:33:22,654 DEBUG http-outgoing-0: connecting to www.wikipedia.org/91.198.174.192:443
2020-02-06 10:33:22,654 DEBUG Connecting socket to www.wikipedia.org/91.198.174.192:443 with timeout 3 MINUTES
2020-02-06 10:33:22,759 DEBUG Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
2020-02-06 10:33:22,759 DEBUG Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2020-02-06 10:33:22,759 DEBUG Starting handshake
2020-02-06 10:33:23,192 DEBUG Secure session established
2020-02-06 10:33:23,192 DEBUG  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2020-02-06 10:33:23,192 DEBUG  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
2020-02-06 10:33:23,192 DEBUG  peer principal: CN=*.wikipedia.org, O="Wikimedia Foundation, Inc.", L=San Francisco, ST=California, C=US
2020-02-06 10:33:23,193 DEBUG  peer alternative names: [*.wikipedia.org, *.wikimedia.org, *.wmfusercontent.org, *.wikimediafoundation.org, *.wiktionary.org, *.wikivoyage.org, *.wikiversity.org, *.wikisource.org, *.wikiquote.org, *.wikinews.org, *.wikidata.org, *.wikibooks.org, wikimedia.org, *.mediawiki.org, wikipedia.org, wikiquote.org, mediawiki.org, wmfusercontent.org, w.wiki, wikimediafoundation.org, wikibooks.org, wiktionary.org, wikivoyage.org, wikidata.org, wikiversity.org, wikisource.org, wikinews.org, *.m.wikipedia.org, *.m.wiktionary.org, *.m.wikivoyage.org, *.m.wikiquote.org, *.m.wikiversity.org, *.m.wikisource.org, *.m.wikimedia.org, *.m.wikinews.org, *.m.wikidata.org, *.m.wikibooks.org, *.planet.wikimedia.org, *.m.mediawiki.org]
2020-02-06 10:33:23,193 DEBUG  issuer principal: CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
2020-02-06 10:33:23,196 DEBUG http-outgoing-0: connection established 192.168.43.143:55022<->91.198.174.192:443
2020-02-06 10:33:23,196 DEBUG ep-00000000: connected http-outgoing-0
2020-02-06 10:33:23,196 DEBUG ep-00000000: endpoint connected
2020-02-06 10:33:23,197 DEBUG ex-00000001: executing GET / HTTP/1.1
2020-02-06 10:33:23,197 DEBUG ep-00000000: start execution ex-00000001
2020-02-06 10:33:23,197 DEBUG ep-00000000: executing exchange ex-00000001 over http-outgoing-0
2020-02-06 10:33:23,198 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 >> GET / HTTP/1.1
2020-02-06 10:33:23,198 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate
2020-02-06 10:33:23,198 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 >> Host: www.wikipedia.org
2020-02-06 10:33:23,198 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: keep-alive
2020-02-06 10:33:23,198 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.0-beta8-SNAPSHOT (Java/1.8.0_181)
2020-02-06 10:33:23,402 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2020-02-06 10:33:23,403 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Date: Wed, 05 Feb 2020 20:39:26 GMT
2020-02-06 10:33:23,403 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: s-maxage=86400, must-revalidate, max-age=3600
2020-02-06 10:33:23,403 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Server: ATS/8.0.5
2020-02-06 10:33:23,404 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << X-ATS-Timestamp: 1580935166
2020-02-06 10:33:23,404 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << ETag: W/"12be8-59c0633ed3519"
2020-02-06 10:33:23,404 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/html
2020-02-06 10:33:23,404 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jan 2020 14:22:18 GMT
2020-02-06 10:33:23,405 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Backend-Timing: D=320 t=1579084179579408
2020-02-06 10:33:23,405 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Content-Encoding: gzip
2020-02-06 10:33:23,405 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Vary: Accept-Encoding
2020-02-06 10:33:23,405 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << X-Varnish: 118503554 495852195
2020-02-06 10:33:23,406 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Age: 46437
2020-02-06 10:33:23,406 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << X-Cache: cp3062 miss, cp3052 hit/600912
2020-02-06 10:33:23,406 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << X-Cache-Status: hit-front
2020-02-06 10:33:23,407 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Server-Timing: cache;desc="hit-front"
2020-02-06 10:33:23,407 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload
2020-02-06 10:33:23,407 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: WMF-Last-Access=06-Feb-2020;Path=/;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Mon, 09 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT
2020-02-06 10:33:23,407 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: WMF-Last-Access-Global=06-Feb-2020;Path=/;Domain=.wikipedia.org;HttpOnly;secure;Expires=Mon, 09 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT
2020-02-06 10:33:23,408 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << X-Client-IP: 213.55.225.99
2020-02-06 10:33:23,418 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: GeoIP=CH:ZH:Zurich:47.37:8.55:v4; Path=/; secure; Domain=.wikipedia.org
2020-02-06 10:33:23,418 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Accept-Ranges: bytes
2020-02-06 10:33:23,418 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 18800
2020-02-06 10:33:23,419 DEBUG http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
2020-02-06 10:33:23,429 DEBUG ex-00000001: connection can be kept alive for -1 MILLISECONDS
2020-02-06 10:33:23,437 DEBUG Cookie accepted [WMF-Last-Access="06-Feb-2020", domain:www.wikipedia.org, path:/, expiry:Mon Mar 09 01:00:00 CET 2020]
2020-02-06 10:33:23,438 DEBUG Cookie accepted [WMF-Last-Access-Global="06-Feb-2020", domain:wikipedia.org, path:/, expiry:Mon Mar 09 01:00:00 CET 2020]
2020-02-06 10:33:23,438 DEBUG Cookie accepted [GeoIP="CH:ZH:Zurich:47.37:8.55:v4", domain:wikipedia.org, path:/, expiry:null]
----------------------------------------
200 OK
SSL protocol TLSv1.2
SSL cipher suite TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
2020-02-06 10:33:23,467 DEBUG http-outgoing-0: close connection GRACEFUL
2020-02-06 10:33:23,468 DEBUG ep-00000000: endpoint closed
2020-02-06 10:33:23,468 DEBUG ep-00000000: endpoint closed
2020-02-06 10:33:23,468 DEBUG ep-00000000: discarding endpoint
2020-02-06 10:33:23,468 DEBUG ep-00000000: releasing endpoint
2020-02-06 10:33:23,469 DEBUG ep-00000000: connection released [route: {s}->https://www.wikipedia.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 25]
2020-02-06 10:33:23,469 DEBUG Shutdown connection pool GRACEFUL
2020-02-06 10:33:23,469 DEBUG Connection pool shut down
```

Comment: Thanks, are you saying that Conscrypt can only be used with HttpAsyncClient, and not with the regular HttpClient? Ideally, I'd like to figure out how to make it work with the regular HttpClient.

Comment: Hmm. No, I am ot saying that but I have actually never tested the classic HttpClient with the Conscrypt provider. I will do so and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks! Even better, it would make life so much easier to find a way to replace JSSE with Conscrypt system-wide so even regular HttpsUrlConnections can use Conscrypt without special configuration.

Comment: See my update. Conscrypt basically works for me without any special configuration.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it is the answer to the main question of how to use Conscrypt. Unfortunately, on MacOS, your exact code still doesn't work for me, and I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
 at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)`

Comment: Raise a JIRA with the project and attache a complete context log of the session https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT

Comment: This is so strange. I tested your code on Linux on an entirely different machine (root box in the cloud), and I get `Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:383)`. I enabled all logging (as documented here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) and it isn't getting to the stage where any log messages appear. Have you tested your code standalone?

Comment: Yes, I have. Do you think I have hand crafted all those log entries? Please make sure you are using HttpClient 5.0-beta7 or the latest snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've created a test case to replicate the issue, including debug logs on both MacOS and Linux, and submitted it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-2050

Comment: You should have mentioned you were using OpenJDK 13 from the start.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. It never occurred to me that it could be JDK13 related, I thought it was just a mistake in my code.